# Ordering of VisibleLayers in Infowindow by clicking on map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to display the information of multiple layers on infowindow by onclick event in the proper order of layers they exist on the map.
I have written some code for this, but the infowindow displays layer information with different layerorder on different clicks.

i.e on one click infowindow display the layer information with order

- layerID:3
- layerID:2

  and in some other click it shows with order
- layerID:2
- layerID:3

Actually we are accessing the service in the code by using

```
setProxyPage: function () {
            //Set rule to use proxy to access services without going through web adaptor
            //https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html
            esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = app.appConfig.ProxyUrl;
            urlUtils.addProxyRule({
                proxyUrl: esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl,
                urlPrefix: app.appConfig.ArcGISServerUrl
            });
        },

var visibleLayers = array.filter(app.mapTOC.getVisibleMapLayers(), function (layer) {
                    return layer.infoTemplate != null;
                });
                
                //handeka US2325 May 9/2016 popup draw order fix, reverse the array so layers drawn on top will be processed first
                //visibleLayers.reverse();
                
                var querys = []; 
                dojo.forEach(visibleLayers, function (layer, index) {
                    //Identify the features that intersect the point the user selected
                    //When all tasks have returned, load the infowindow and show it on the map
                    //might be faster to use queryTask but domain based fields return the codes not the display values and then you need to also fix those up
                    var identifyTask = new IdentifyTask(layer.mapServiceURL);
                    var identifyParams = new IdentifyParameters();
                    identifyParams.tolerance = 5;
                    identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
                    identifyParams.layerIds = [layer.layerIndex];
                    identifyParams.layerDefinitions = layer.dynamicLayer.layerDefinitions || [];
                    identifyParams.layerOption = IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_TOP; //only identify the top most visible layer, we are passing only 1 layer id at a time in so this always works
                    identifyParams.width = app.mapUtil.map.width;
                    identifyParams.height = app.mapUtil.map.height;
                    identifyParams.geometry = mapPoint;
                    identifyParams.mapExtent = app.mapUtil.map.extent;
                    querys.push(identifyTask.execute(identifyParams));
                });
```

Please suggest to me where to modify the code to get same layerID order in infowindow for all clicks on map.